# PayPal Sandbox postback failure

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

We are doing some order testing on a development site with PayPal Sandbox but are getting the following error in Magento's `var/log/payment_paypal_standard.log` file when the IPN is received from PayPal:

```
PayPal IPN postback failure. See paypal_unknown_ipn.log for details.
```

Looking at the rest of the log in `payment_paypal_standard.log` we have the
 following:

```
[postback_to] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr
[postback_result] =>
[exception] => PayPal IPN postback failure. See paypal_unknown_ipn.log for details.
[__pid] => 30534
```

We have PayPal enabled on our live site (on the same server) and it's working properly so not sure why the sandbox IPN's are failing.

The PayPal IPN history shows a code 200 for the IPN and the request is logged in the site's access_log file, so the IPN is being received successfully but the postback is failing.

The following error is logged in `var/log/exception.log`:

```
2016-03-08T16:07:41+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Exception' with message 'PayPal IPN postback failure. See paypal_unknown_ipn.log for details.' in /var/www/vhosts/dev-2.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php:155
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/dev-2.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php(114): Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn->_postBack(Object(Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl))
#1 /var/www/vhosts/dev-2.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/IpnController.php(43): Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn->processIpnRequest(Array, Object(Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/dev-2.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Paypal_IpnController->indexAction()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/dev-2.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/dev-2.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/dev-2.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/dev-2.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/dev-2.domain.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Running Magento CE 1.7.0.2 and tested on PHP 5.3 and 5.4.

How can we troubleshoot this to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the problem is in your curl library (which is very old, probably version 7.19.7 because you are using an old PHP version). PayPal Sandbox supports only TLS 1.2 while PayPal live supports TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. You can read some more information here - https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ssl-security-update . To be sure that this is the problem you can log the curl response in **lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php** -> `public function read()`, after `$response = curl_exec($this->_getResource());` add something like this:

```
Mage::log($this->getError(), Zend_Log::INFO, 'curl.log', true);
```

and it should return "SSL connect error". The solution is to update your **curl library** to at least **version 7.34.0**.

Comment: Just added the line you suggested and ran a test order, but no curl.log file was created. Any other options for catching the presumed error?

Comment: Try to log the `$response`. Also check if Curl.php is rewritten or copied to **app/code/local/Varien/Http/Adapter**.

Comment: Ignore what I said previously - I was editing the file on the _wrong_ site! The `curl.log` works and does indeed show `SSL connect error`. Will look at upgrading the prehistoric version of curl.